# Different behaviour between CString operators "+=" and "+"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015

While migrating an application from VisualStudio 2005 to VisualStudio 2015 we found a different behaviour in some code that concatenates CString instances when that code is built with VS2015.
So, I've created a simple Win32 console application to demonstrate the problem.

The console application (using MFC as shared dll and Unicode charachter set) executes this simple function:

```
void f()
{
   CString x( '\0' );

   CString r( 'a' );
   r += x;
   CString rr( 'a' );
   rr = rr + x;

   int rSize = r.GetLength();
   int rrSize = rr.GetLength();

   assert( rSize == rrSize ); // This assert fires when compiled and run 
                              // under Visual Studio 2015!
}
```

It shows that, when a CString containing a '\0' char is concatenated to another CString instance, using '+=' or using '+' leads to different results!

When '+=' is used the size of the result is calculated counting all chars till the first '\0'... hence the final size is 1!
Conversely, when the operator '+' is used the result CString size is 2, that is the sum of the sizes of the concatenated instances!

In VisualStudio 2005 the result size is always the sum of the sizes of the concatenated instances!

I [filed a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2161135) to Microsoft a few weeks ago, but up until now I have no answer from those guys.

My questions:
 1. Have somebody stumbled onto this bug in the MCF library??
 2. How have you worked around this bug? We are thinking to ban the use of the += operator or else to replace the CString class with the a custom class, but all of this seems to me "a bit" invasive.

Comment: Just FYI - the same result on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what happens when you add to `x` before adding `x` to the other strings? Like `x += "Hello, World!";`?

Comment: CString's `Append()` method (used in `+=` operator) has this *strange* comment: `//Make sure we don't read pass end of the terminating NULL`, followed by `nLength = StringLengthN(pszSrc, nLength);`. This will **NOT** let any zeroes into the CString!

Comment: Quote from the docs: "CString accepts null-terminated C-style strings, but does not retain the null character in the stored character data."  That's where the problem started, stay a mile away from '\0'.

Comment: @HansPassant - re: `"but does not retain the null character"` - if only that was true! This code (pardon for missing formatting in the comment): `CString x('\0');
 x += "b";
 CString rr( 'a' );
 rr = rr + x;` will produce a **THREE** character string "a[ZERO]b"...

Comment: @HansPassant: That quote does not apply here. The OP uses a c'tor that takes a **character literal**, not a string literal. Apart from that, the [CStringT Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) documentation explicitly calls out, that *"it is possible to create CStringT instances that contain embedded null characters"* (even though it isn't recommended).

Comment: @JohnSensebe
Appending a string to x before append it to the other string has the same net effect: r.GetLength() continues to return 1 whereas rr.GetLength() returns 15

Comment: @ HansPassant, IInspectable, Vlad...
Yes... CString accepts and retains the null character and, at least in VS2005, it worked very well.
I could accept Microsoft decision to break backward compatibility discarding embedded '\0's; if our legacy app uses CString in a "not so appreciated" way it's our fault!
That said, in no way I can accept that the result of r += x is different from the result of r = r + x.
In my little opinion this is a **serious** bug.
Thanks to everyone,
        Nicola

Comment: @NicolaIuretigh Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. I was thinking it might be doing something along the lines IInspectable wrote in his answer, but I could not confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the [CStringT Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) contains the following cryptic statement:

> Although it is possible to create CStringT instances that contain embedded null characters, we recommend against it. **Calling methods and operators on CStringT objects that contain embedded null characters can produce unintended results.**

Frankly, I don't really know what to make of the final sentence. I take it as a warning to be careful when embedding null characters. Regardless, contractual guarantees should still hold when doing so.

**Analysis:**

This apparently is not the case with [CStringT::operator+=](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws50yfk5.aspx), though. In the sample code of the question the implementation of `operator+=` invokes the

```
CSimpleStringT& operator+=( const CSimpleStringT& strSrc )
```

overload, which modifies the current instance by calling

```
void Append( const CSimpleStringT& strSrc )
```

which in turn calls

```
void Append( PCXSTR pszSrc, int nLength )
```

passing an explicit length argument. This should suffice to deal with C-style strings with embedded null characters. Oddly enough, the implementation then starts to second-guess the input by calling `StringLengthN(pszSrc, nLength)` (implemented as a call to [wcsnlen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50ty2zh.aspx)), to re-calculate the length of *pszSrc*. This returns 0 for the `CStringT` instance *x* in the sample code.

**Result:**

To me, this appears to be a bug in the implementation. Incidentally, if you reverse the arguments to `operator+=` (i.e. `x += r;` vs. `r += x;`), the result is a string with length 2, as expected.

**Resolution:**

The only clean solution would be to have Microsoft acknowledge the bug, and provide a fix for it. I wouldn't hold my breath, though, as Microsoft usually doesn't ship bug fixes, if they change behavior of a shipped product.

If you cannot convince Microsoft to fix that bug, your only other option is to not use the operator with undesired behavior. One way would be to use another string class. A well established replacement is [std::wstring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which you can convert to a `CStringW` where necessary (`CStringW cstr(s.c_str(), s.length());`).

---

**Update (2016-09-13):**

The OP filed a [defect report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2161135) with Microsoft, and they acknowledged the bug. A bug fix was implemented, but *"it won't appear until the next major version of the libraries (which may not necessarily ship in the current [2016-03-31] Visual Studio vNext)"*.

Comment: Thank you @IInspectable for your accurate answer.

Comment: In these moments we are evaluating our alternatives for a workaround to this bug.
Unfortunately our super-legacy application is full of code which could potentially encounter CString instances embedding one or more null characters and whatever we choose it will be a "bloodbath"!!
;)
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the "cryptic statement" means "We can implement this any way we want, so don't count on a particular result."